# Upload image using Node js and electron. (convert from c# code)

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, electron, restsharp

I'm converting an application from c# to electron and i have some problems when i try to make a request to upload an image on a server (not my server).

For c# i used RestSharp library and all worked fine.

```
    private void UploadImage(string id)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://www.website.com")
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
        };
        string path = @"D:\Downloads\image.jpg";

        var request = new RestRequest("/upload?id=" + id, Method.POST);
        request.AddFile("myfile", File.ReadAllBytes(path), Path.GetFileName(path), "image/jpeg");

        request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        client.Execute(request);
    }
```

How can i convert this code in Node js? The only thing i could found was code that uploaded to their own server and that does not work for me.

This is what i tried in Node js

```
var fs = require('fs');
    var request = require('request');
    fs.createReadStream("D:\Downloads\image.jpg").pipe(request.post("https://www.website.com/upload?id=" + productId, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }));
```

Using the code above i get status code 200 and the body response is telling me that no image was select. So the request is working, but sending the image doesn't.

Comment: Could you please expand on what "does not work for me" means?.  Do you get an error, and if so, what?   Does your inner function (the one that calls `console.log`) get called?  Or does something else happen?

Comment: the console.log gets called but no image is uploaded to the server

Comment: Which `console.log` line gets called, the one with `error` or the one with `response`?  What does `body` contain?  Also, what's the status code of the response?  (To get this, see the code on the [request library GitHub page](https://github.com/request/request).)  Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i did in order to solve the problem. Maybe it will help somebody else too.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var req = request.post(uploadURL, function (err, resp, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error!');
    } else {
      console.log('URL: ' + body);
    }
  });
  var form = req.form();
  form.append('myfile', fs.createReadStream("path\to\image.jpg"), {
    filename: "image.jpg",
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to use the same technique using Electron to upload files to my localhost test server, but no luck. My code returns as successful in the console, but no file is ever uploaded. Is this something you came across, or is there anything you may be able to see I'm doing differently?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

var uploadURL = 'http://localhost:80/sandbox/img';

var req = request.post(uploadURL, function (err, resp, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
});

var form = req.form();

form.append('upload', fs.createReadStream("C:/nodejs/dave/assets/img/brand_logos/logo.jpg"), {
    filename: "logo.jpg",
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
});
```

Below is the response I get, which I'm assuming is expected...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://localhost/sandbox/img/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.0.23 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I suggest you make a new question, You won't get any answers here.